# Linking Bluetooth and Ethernet packets

Tags: security, bluetooth, wifi, ethernet

If I am listening to Ethernet packets going across a Wi-Fi network using a card in monitor mode, and listening to Bluetooth packets using an Ubertooth, is there any way to link both types of packets to devices? As far as I am aware there no commonality between the Bluetooth BD_ADDR and the Ethernet MAC address of a device.

Essentially: is there a common denominator in Wi-Fi and Bluetooth packets that can be used to link the two?

**Edit**: just to add, the device in question is a smartphone.

Comment: Nope. You cannot correlate MAC addresses. Does the same data travel through both interfaces?

Comment: No - it would be completely separate data. What I'm looking to do is build up a picture of the devices in the area, and hopefully correlate Bluetooth and Wi-Fi packets to develop as great a picture as possible of individual devices.